# In Nuxt, prop is not passed to layout's slot

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I am trying to pass a `language` prop from parent (layout) to children (footer, nav, and main part of page). It passes to nav and footer but not to main part of the page (in this case: login). I get a `language is not defined` error. Why? How to fix it?

(Do not confuse with `languages`, that one is composable consisting of strings and imported automatically for all components.)

pages/login.vue:

```
<template>
  <AuthForm kind="login" :language="language" :message="message" @submitted="login" />
</template>

<script setup>
import AuthForm from "../components/auth-form.vue";
const message = ref({})
const props = defineProps(['language'])
async function login(value) {
  try {
    const data = await api('login', value);
    message = { type: 'success', message: languages[language]['loggedIn'] }
  } catch (error) {
    message = { type: 'error', message: languages[language][error.statusMessage] }
  }
}
</script>
<style></style>
```

layouts/default.vue:

```
<template>
    <Navbar :language="language" />
    <slot :language="language" />
    <Footer :language="language" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue"
import Navbar from "../components/navbar.vue"
import Footer from "../components/footer.vue"
import { watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route = useRoute();
const langCookie = useCookie('language');
watch(
    () => route.query.hl,
    (newLang) => { langCookie.value = newLang; },
    { immediate: true }
);
const language = computed({
    get(){
        return route.query.hl || langCookie.value || 'az'
    }
})
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Try props.language. You haven't defined variable language anywhere in login.vue. Or console.log(props) and look how to get language.

Comment: @digitalniweb it didn't work.

Comment: Actually, using props the way OP has, works. I use it like this in my Nuxt app. What I wonder is if the computed ref that is passed through, is correctly received. What are you doing with `language` in `AuthForm`?